# Mirth Connect save time-stamp

Tags: mirth

I have a Mirth Channel that takes data from MS SQL Server, creates an HL7 message for a file drop.

I want to run the query to only consider data younger than the last time we ran the query. How do we get Mirth Connect to save the old time stamp so that it can be used as part of the next query and survive between reboots? We cannot modify the database we are pulling the data from (otherwise we would just update the status table).

Do you have any suggestions for how, within Mirth Connect, we can save the timestamp of a given query to use in the next query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options:

1. I think you could store some unique identifier and the timestamp in
   one of the global maps and it will stick around between channel
   calls. Not 100% on this one.
2. You can always write it to a file then
   read it later. Depending on how your channel flows, this could be an
   advantage. A file reader source could read that file and do queries
   since the timestamp recorded in that file (or even the file
   timestamp itself!).
3. The next option is to create a table in the same
   or a different database (like a local SQLLite instance) and handle
   it in SQL.

Comment: Considering the option 3, sqllite, what would be the appropriate place that?

Comment: Home directory of the user that the mcserver runs as if it needs to survive restarts. System temp directory if not. Put it in a clear well named path and put a README file in the same location.

Comment: I meant, were in Mirth Connect?

Comment: Just add another destination. First one does whatever actual work you need, second one writes the persistent data to your file or SQL table